# Linux Won't Run

Tags: boot, server, google-chrome, connection, chromebook

Wow.

I recently installed Ubuntu on my Chromebook C720. I installed it using Crouton, so it runs Chrome and Ubuntu side by side. I can switch between them with a hot key. For more information on my installation method, you can check out this article: http://www.howtogeek.com/162120/how-to-install-ubuntu-linux-on-your-chromebook-with-crouton/.

I recently ubdated my linux system (I believe it was to 14.04 Trusty). Anyway, now I can't get Ubuntu to run on my computer anymore since the update. I press `ctr+alt+t` to get the terminal on Chrome. Then I type `shell` and follow up with the command `sudo startxfce4`. And nothing. It presents with this error: `EE: Server terminated with error (1). Closing log file.` It also goes on to say: `/usr/bin/xinit: unable to connect to X server: Connection refused.`

Does anyone have the slightest idea of what is going on here?

Comment: tried simply running `startx`  ?

Answer (score 1):

Yes if your having trouble usually doing ,

```
sudo sh ~/Downloads/crouton -n trusty -u
```

and/or u can powerwash your Chromebook and reinstall again